# django template href external file

Tags: django, file, href

I use this template to list links:

```
<a class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm" href="{{ oLink.link }}" target="_blank">{{ oLink.text }}</a>
```

oLink.link could be something like: `'http://www.google.com'` or `'\\shared_files\GMO-M0960\GMO-M0960_01.pdf'`

oLink.text is just a simple text to be used.

Links reference to another webpage work correctly, but links reference to files inside a shared directory don't (new window never opens)
It works only if I right click on the link and then copy its url in a new window.

Do I need to configure something? This seems to be so simple.